# django-cms absolute urls to pages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to get a list of all pages I have published in my Django-CMS application but I can't seem to get it to render the language-specific urls.

in my settings I have specified:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('sv', 'Svenska'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

I go in to the admin site, I create a contact-page (That is not site-home) and set different slugs on different languages, 'contact-sv' and 'contact-en' for instance.

Then I have a view that gets a page

```
from cms.models import Page
page = Page.objects.published()[1]
print 'swe:', page.get_absolute_url(language='sv')
print 'eng:', page.get_absolute_url(language='en')
```

I then get This output:

```
swe: /contact-en/
eng: /contact-en/
```

When I expected the swe-url to be /sv/contact-sv/

I don't need the langage prefix to the path, I can prepend that to the path but I need the language specific path.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? I've run into the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I can offer you no better solution than to wait for the 2.4 release which will use Django's built-in i18n_urlpatterns to handle this, which should fix the issue you have, for now, your answer is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a better way to do it but now I loop through titles on the page object.

```
for title in page.title_set.all():
    print title.language, title.slug
```

It works, but I do not like it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the sitemap strategy. django cms has it's own sitemap class that runs this code:

```
class CMSSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        all_titles = Title.objects.public().filter(
            Q(redirect='') | Q(redirect__isnull=True),
            page__login_required=False,
            page__site=Site.objects.get_current(),
        ).order_by('page__path')
        return all_titles
```